# cast "1900-01-01T00:00:00" string value to date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've watching trough stack overflow to find the answer and I can't find it I want to cast this string value "1900-01-01T00:00:00" to Date format, I was trying with some formats like those:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss +zzzz"
"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.A"
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
```

but anyone of those its working.
and I want the date format like this

```
"dd-mm-yyyy"
```

Hope you can help me!

Thanks.

Comment: You first need to convert the string to a `Date` so you first need a matching date format. None of the ones you've listed are even close to matching a string such as "1900-01-01T00:00:00".

Comment: "I was trying with some formats like those": You may have better chances at lotery. A tip? Write the datestring ABOVE your format at try to match it. For instance ""EEE, ..." was NEVER gonna match it. and read what each letter or couple of them means http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns Another tip: Break your string into multiple pieces and try to find the format for each piece.

Answer (score 1):

It is a two step process, first converting `1900-01-01T00:00:00` (known as a RFC 3999 or ISO 8601 date, referred to the specifications that define this format) into a `Date` object, and then converting that `Date` object back to a string in the form of `01-01-1900`:

1. To convert your string in the form of `1900-01-01T00:00:00` into a `Date` object, you can use [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter):

   ```
   let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
   formatter.formatOptions.remove(.withTimeZone)

   let date = formatter.date(from: string)!
   ```

   That is equivalent to the following `DateFormat`, in which one has to manually set the `locale` to `en_US_POSIX` (because RFC 3999/ISO 8601 dates use a Gregorian calendar, regardless of what the device's default calendar type) and sets the `timeZone` to GMT/Zulu, because usually RFC 3999/ISO 8601 dates are representing GMT unless specified otherwise:

   ```
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
   formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
   formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

   let date = formatter.date(from: string)!
   ```

   For more information about the importance of timezones and locales in parsing RFC 3999 and ISO 8601 dates, see Apple's [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html).
2. Then, to convert that `Date` object to a string into `01-01-1900` (day, month, and year), you'd use a format string of `dd-MM-yyyy` (note the uppercase `MM` for "month", to distinguish it from `mm` for "minute"):

   ```
   let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
   formatter2.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

   let string = formatter2.string(from: date)
   ```

   Two observations regarding the `dateFormat` string:

   - If this string is for displaying to the user, you might use use [`dateStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415411-datestyle) rather than [`dateFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1413514-dateformat), e.g.:

     ```
     formatter2.dateStyle = .short
     ```

     While this will generate a slightly different format, e.g. `dd/MM/yy`, the virtue of this approach is that the string will be localized (e.g. UK users will see `MM/dd/yyyy`, their preferred way of seeing short dates).

     It just depends upon the purpose of your `dd-MM-yyyy` format. If it's for internal purposes, go ahead and use `dateFormat`. But if it's for showing dates in your UI, use `dateStyle` instead, and enjoy the localization that `DateFormatter` does automatically for you. For more information, see "Working With User-Visible Representations of Dates and Times" section of the [`DateFormatter` reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).
   - Note that in the absence of a `timeZone` specified for this second formatter, it assumes that while the ISO 8601 date was in GMT, that you want to see the date in your local timezone. For example, (`1900-01-01T00:00:00` GMT was Dec 31, 1899 at 4pm in California). If you want to see the date string of the original ISO 8601 object, not corrected for timezones, you'd just set the `timeZone` of this second formatter to be GMT as well, e.g.

     ```
     formatter2.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
     ```

---

As others have pointed out, you want to avoid unnecessarily re-instantiating `DateFormatter` objects. So you might put these formatters in properties that are instantiated only once, or use an `extension`:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let customInputFormatter: ISO8601DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        formatter.formatOptions.remove(.withTimeZone)
        return formatter
    }()

    static let customOutputFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)  // if you want date in your local timezone, remove this line
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

And then:

```
let input = "1900-01-01T00:00:00"
let date = DateFormatter.customInputFormatter.date(from: input)!
let output = DateFormatter.customOutputFormatter.string(from: date)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do custom date formatters:

```
extension DateFormatter {

    static let inDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter
    }()

    static let outDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

And then use it like:

```
if let date = DateFormatter.inDateFormatter.date(from: "1900-01-01T00:00:00") {
    let newDateString = DateFormatter.outDateFormatter.string(from: date);
    print(newDateString) //prints 01-00-1900
}
```

This avoids any potential performance issues and is clear at the point of use, while still being concise.

Comment: "dd-mm-yyyy" is wrong `MM` is for month `mm` is for minutes

Comment: That was the format specified by the OP. Obviously that's easily customized.

Comment: why would you use day/minutes/year?

Comment: why are you asking me? :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, it looks easy all try thanks for your help @PEEJWEEJ

Comment: Sorry, I thought the down-vote was obvious because of the above exchange. I down-voted because the OP was obviously mistaken in his `dd-mm-yyyy` reference (clearly he simply wasn't attentive to the capitalization of `mm`), and it's silly to repeat it here as if you seriously thought the OP intended day-minute-year. As this stands, this is just likely to be a source of confusion for future readers. Plus, your `inDateFormatter` should specify a `locale` of `en_US_POSIX`, and perhaps specify a `timeZone`, too.

Comment: lol...yes the time zone and locale could be added (depending on the situation)...but I still answered the actual question they asked but because the OP put something wrong and I used those 2 characters, it was a bad answer? Geeze...high standards for this guy. 

Comment: Sorry if a basic answer to a basic question doesn't contain all the information needed in every possible case, I guess I should make it my full time job to control for other people's laziness . Have fun with your holy war. Make sure not to die on your mole hill 

Answer (score -1):

Use this extension I created, where you can pass the format as a parameter.

```
extension String
{
    func  toDate( dateFormat format  : String) -> Date
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
        {
            return date
        }
        print("Invalid arguments ! Returning Current Date . ")
        return Date()
    }
}
"1900-01-01T00:00:00".toDate(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")  //Plyground call test
```

Comment: this will create a DateFormatter object every single time that you convert the string to Date

Comment: FYI, it's generally not a good idea to create your formatter more than once. This extension makes it concise, but expensive if you're doing this a lot. Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: Returning the Date() instead of an optional and nil is ugly

Comment: You should also set the date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX"

Comment: Ok, well I'll try thanks all of you for your comments and answer @MagoNicolasPalacios